# Find out the steps missing to change the icon in .NET MAUI

Tags: .net, maui

I want to change the current .NET MAUI icon and replace with mine. I followed the steps provided in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=ios but still icon remains the same.
For the second step I copied the same way of other projects in changing the icon but it is still the same.
I want to see the changes in iOS, help me to know if I'm missing any steps in changing the app icon for iOS.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H91ZX.jpg)

Prepared a new app icon image in a square format and saved it in a PNG format.
Located the project I want to change the app icon for.
In the "Properties" window, selected the "Application" tab.
Clicked the button next to the "Icon" field.
In the "Select Icon" dialog box, clicked the "Browse" button and navigate it to the location where my new app icon image is saved.
Selected the new app icon image and clicked "Open" and I selected the icon image that I want to save for the changes.
Last step, I uninstall the app from my iPhone and connected back to see the changes.
When I run the code, it asked me to install the app but the icon did not change.
I want to see the changes in iOS, help me to know if I'm missing any steps in changing the app icon for iOS.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm having exactly the same problem, I can't change the app icon (or even the splashscreen, whereas on Android everything works fine).

Answer (score 0):

it is mentioned in the guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=ios to use svg format, and .net maui will convert it to PNG. do you do that step ?

firstly, you can convert your current png file to svg. many online converter is available.example:  https://convertio.co/ . Make it a basic svg file

Then, you call the file the same default file name appicon.svg. You edit in your .csproj

the same is mentioned in
Refer to https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3755#issuecomment-1063138958 .

Answer (score 0):

Your steps are right, but you also need to set it on the ios platform.

You can check this article about the [Platform-specific configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=ios#tabpanel_1_ios).

For ios, you can change codes below in the `Info.plist`.

```
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/iconname.appiconset</string>
```